# Prevent duplicate objects in classes/instance access with singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

The use is to provide .instance access, also to prevent duplicate objects of those classes.

Is this a good code implementation of a singleton?

```
template <typename T> class singleton
{
public:
    static T *ms_singleton;

    singleton()
    {
        assert(!ms_singleton);
        long offset = (long)(T *) 1 - (long)(singleton <T> *)(T *) 1;
        ms_singleton = (T *)((long) this + offset);
    }

    virtual ~singleton()
    {
        assert(ms_singleton);
        ms_singleton = 0;
    }

    static T &instance()
    {
        assert(ms_singleton);
        return (*ms_singleton);
    }

    static T &Instance()
    {
        assert(ms_singleton);
        return (*ms_singleton);
    }

    static T *instance_ptr()
    {
        return (ms_singleton);
    }
};
template <typename T> T *singleton <T>::ms_singleton = NULL;
```

How I use it:

```
class test1: public singleton<test2>
{
    // Something
};
```

If not, what is wrong here? What should i rewrite here?

Comment: Why not use Meyers's Singleton if really you want singleton.

Comment: This is not a singleton at all as you have a public constructor.

Comment: And your offset computation with cast is strange... what do you want to accomplish ?

Comment: _"Is this a good code implementation of a singleton?"_ Definitely not.

Comment: [What is so bad about singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your singleton class has some weird things. Like you relying on the constructor to do a debug-build run-time check that it can be constructed or not, in your constructor.

A typical singleton class have the constructors private so it can only be constructed by the accessor function. It also should not rely on e.g. `assert` which is a macro which is disabled in release builds.

A simple non-inheritable singleton class could look like this:

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& instance()
    {
        static Singleton actual_instance;
        return actual_instance;
    }

    // Other public member functions

private:
    // Private constructor
    Singleton() = default;
};
```

By having the constructor private, it means no one else can't attempt to construct an instance. It also means that this is checked at the time of compilation by the compiler itself.

Also by having the actual instance of the object as a static variable *and* initialized at definition inside the accessor function, mean that the creation of the instance is thread-safe.

---

To expand it and make it generic like you seem to want to do, then you need to make the base class constructor protected. You also need to make the base class a `friend` in the inherited class.

The child-class still need to make its constructor private to prevent accidental construction.

Updated the base class would then look something like

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& instance()
    {
        static T actual_instance;
        return actual_instance;
    }

protected:
    Singleton() = default;
};
```

A child class might look something like

```
class ChildSingleton : public Singleton<ChildSingleton>
{
public:
    // Public member functions...

private:
    friend class Singleton<ChildSingleton>;

    // Private constructor
    ChildSingleton() = default;
};
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `static Singleton* actual_instance = new Singleton;` over `static Singleton actual_instance;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Not really no, probably some problem with my thinking.

Comment: Look what clang 3.4 says  http://prntscr.com/cl331l

Comment: OK.  I have seen others do it and I was curious if there was some reason for it.  I try to avoid `new` as much as I can.

Comment: @Smartx221 You probably did something wrong.

Comment: @Smartx221 That was because I return a reference to an instance, and forgot to dereference the pointer. Fixed now when not using pointers.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [Needs small fixes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a33e22d0b0db215) but works as expected.

Comment: Copy-constructor should also be private or better deleted.